# Asterisk sever configuration for session Audit

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk

is there any way to configure Asterisk (11.6.0) server for session Audit so that the audit can be done through  re-INVITE or UPDATE to the call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No asterisk not customizable on sip message level.

If you need work on message level, consider http://kamailio.org or http://opensips.org projects.

Comment: thanks for your response..can you please help me out to configure PARK and ORBIT on Asterisk 11.06.

In features.conf i have added

[general]

parkext => 700                 
parkpos => 701-720              
context => parkedcalls          
parkinghints = no  



in extensions.conf(i have added)

include => parkedcalls





BUT when i try to park the call,INVITE goes to the same URI which was supposed to be parked.

Comment: Hire expert or install elastix/trixbox/freepbx, it already have all parking contexts set. http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+call+parking